# What was influence of Thomism on the Council of Trent?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, thomas-aquinas, ecumenical-council

What was influence of Thomism on the Council of Trent? Did anyone study this question and write some article, essay or book on this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

St. Thomas had great influence on Trent, and several of his teachings became, almost verbatim, defined dogma at that council. From the encyclical [*Æterni Patris*](https://w2.vatican.va/content/leo-xiii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_l-xiii_enc_04081879_aeterni-patris.html) (1879) on the restoration of Christian philosophy by Pope Leo XIII:

> 22. The ecumenical councils, also, where blossoms the flower of all earthly wisdom, have always been careful to hold Thomas Aquinas in singular honor. In the Councils of [Lyons](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09476c.htm), [Vienna](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52628/1787), [Florence](https://catholicism.org/cantate-domino.html#post-403), and the [Vatican](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.ii.i.html#v.ii.i-p17.13) one might almost say that Thomas took part and presided over the deliberations and decrees of the Fathers, contending against the errors of the Greeks, of heretics and rationalists, with invincible force and with the happiest results. But the chief and special glory of Thomas, one which he has shared with none of the Catholic Doctors, is that **the Fathers of [Trent](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.v.i.i.html) made it part of the order of conclave to lay upon the altar**, together with sacred Scripture and the decrees of the supreme Pontiffs, **the [*Summa [Theologica]*](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/index.html) of Thomas Aquinas**, whence to seek counsel, reason, and inspiration.

See also "[The Twenty-Four Fundamental Theses of Official Catholic Philosophy](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart1.htm)" by P. Lumbreras, O.P., S.T.Lr., Ph.D., and the [Testimonies of the Popes on St. Thomas Aquinas](https://maritain.nd.edu/jmc/etext/thomas6.htm), which cites Berthier, O.P.'s [*Testimonia Ecclesiæ*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3470).