# Looking for a website providing HTML formatted works of Joseph Pohle's 12 volume Dogmatic Theology

Tags: catholicism, resource-request, systematic-theology

There are plenty of websites presenting multi-volume works of St. Thomas Aquinas in HTML formatted chunks such as [New Advent's Summa Theologiae](http://www.newadvent.org/summa/index.html).

I'm looking for a website containing similarly HTML formatted chunks preferably with table of contents for the 12 volume set Dogmatic Theology by [Joseph Pohle, S.J.](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/pohle-joseph).  All I can find is a [PDF version of the books from archive.org](http://iteadthomam.blogspot.com/2017/09/pohle-preuss-dogmatic-theology-12-vols.html), a result of Google digitizing project.  [Logos](https://www.logos.com/product/4724/dogmatic-theology) has it, but it's not free.

It looks like only one of the 12 volumes has been converted, courtesy of  Suzanne Lybarger, David King, and the Online [Distributed Proofreaders](https://www.pgdp.net) Team, and hosted in the Project Gutenberg website: [Grace, Actual and Habitual: A Dogmatic Treatise](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29540).

In lieu of HTML formatted website, clean digital files (PDF, EPUB, etc.) with table of contents are also acceptable.

Comment: @Geremia Thanks.  Edited the question.

Comment: @Geremia.  In Logos product pages, the samples are from the original, such as one that I own, [Summa Theologica](https://www.logos.com/product/4248/summa-theologica), Logos provides the table of contents as well hyperlinked other answers within ST and church father's books quite nicely.  They provide automatic updates whenever they add new hyperlinks when they digitize more books, part of their "upsell" strategy as well.  Starting 2-3 years ago they try to reach out to the Catholics using the [Verbum](https://verbum.com/) brand and packages but the underlying technology is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are EPUBs (and some other formats) from [here](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=series:%22%3DDogmatic%20Theology%22&sort=series.asc):

1. [*God: His Knowability, Essence, and Attributes: A Dogmatic Treatise*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3787)
2. [*The Divine Trinity: A Dogmatic Treatise*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3784)
3. [*God the Author of Nature and the Supernatural: A Dogmatic Treatise*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3786)
4. [*Christology: A Dogmatic Treatise on the Incarnation*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3783)
5. [*Soteriology: A Dogmatic Treatise on the Redemption*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3795)
6. [*Mariology: A Dogmatic Treatise on the Blessed Virgin Mary, Mother of God: With an Appendix on the Worship of the Saints, Relics, and Images*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3789)
7. [*Grace, Actual and Habitual: A Dogmatic Treatise*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3788)
8. [*The Sacraments: A Dogmatic Treatise (vol. 1): The Sacrements in General, Baptism, Confirmation*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3791)
9. [*The Sacraments: A Dogmatic Treatise (vol. 2): The Holy Eucharist*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3792)
10. [*The Sacraments: A Dogmatic Treatise (vol. 3): Penance*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3793)
11. [*The Sacraments: A Dogmatic Treatise (vol. 4): Extreme Unction, Holy Orders, Matrimony*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3794)
12. [*Eschatology or the Catholic Doctrine of the Last Things: A Dogmatic Treatise*](https://isidore.co/calibre/get/EPUB/3785)

Comment: +1 For clean digital format that has table of contents, and that still preserves the footnote superscripts within the text.  +1 for clean OCR of the Greek and Hebrew characters.  +1 for preserving the typesetting.  Tested with [calibre reader](https://calibre-ebook.com/about), looks very good.  Reading with a PDF reader for the original scanned version side by side the EPUB reader make it still easy to read the footnotes in the scanned image.  Thanks!

Comment: @GratefulDisciple The EPUBs have footnotes and EPUB tables of contents now.

Comment: Wow, that's great.  Thanks!  Some day I'd like to try generating EPUB programmatically.  It has all the features I need.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Calibre can do that; cf. its [ebook-convert](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/ebook-convert.html). (The Pohle-Preuss EPUBs were generated by Calibre.)

Comment: @GratefulDisciple In Calibre, you can select a book and hit the "c" key to convert it to EPUB or several other formats.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple There was a small bug in the footnotes (e.g., "9a" wasn't recognized) that's now corrected.