# Did the Early Church Fathers believe in exorcisms?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, eastern-orthodox, church-fathers, exorcism

Both Roman Catholics and Orthodox Christians believe in exorcism (ie the religious or spiritual practice of evicting demons, jinns, or other malevolent spiritual entities from a person), but did the Early Church Fathers believe and perform exorcisms?

Answer (score 6):

The eight [orders](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/Holy7Sacraments-Orders.shtml),

> Major Orders
>
> 1. bishop
> 2. priest
> 3. deacon
>
> Minor Orders
>
> 4. subdeacon
> 5. acolyte
> 6. [**exorcist**](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33476)
> 7. lector
> 8. porter,

which include the minor order of exorcist, were mentioned at the Fourth Council of Carthage, 398 A.D. ([*Pohle*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/73943/1787) [vol. 11](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3794)).

Also, ([*ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=3794)):

> The first mention of the complete series of orders is found in a letter of Pope Cornelius (251–253) to Fabius of Antioch. **The Pontiff states that there are** [were] **among the Roman clergy** forty-two priests, seven deacons, seven subdeacons, forty-two acolytes, and fifty-two **exorcists**, lectors, and porters.<sup>25</sup> While it is not likely that Cornelius himself had instituted the four minor orders mentioned in his letter, they are nowhere enumerated fully and in proper sequence before his time. **St. Cyprian** (+ 258) **speaks of exorcists**, lectors, and acolytes, but makes no mention of porters.